# Magento 2: Setting the product url key with REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, product-urls, url-key

Is it possible? I see no mention of a `url_key` in the Swagger docs.

I have a large database of product I need to import, and the names (which seem to determine the url) are not unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although Swagger doesn't specify "url_key", you can add this attribute value by the following method:

```
{
  "product": {
    ...
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "url_key",
        "value": "<your_value>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: Next time, you can use GET to know the product JSON structure first. Then any customized attributes can be created according to the JSON structure.